# What are the ethical, legal, or career risks of reselling swag I won in a raffle?

Tags: ethics

I recently won a swag from workplace raffle,but my family and friends are really into camping so everyone I know owns a swag so I’m selling it online for cheap. But my workmate says it could get me fired? Is this true

Comment: We cannot say if they can legally fire you, if you don't tell us what country (and maybe state) you are in. If you edit your post and add a country tag, we might be able to give better answers.

Comment: Is it company branded swag?

Answer (score 5):

So - if you are in the US and in a At-Will State - then sure, cause anything can get you fired.

Except for that scenario - could it get your fired? No. But could it reflect poorly on you?

Yes.

That's what your Co-Worker is hinting at - some Management types would feel insulted by such an action (especially in some cultures) and this wouldn't be advisable.

However, ultimately - it's yours to do with as you see fit.

Comment: It is also a little bit different if it is the company's product. If you work for Y and company is giving out Y's widgets, there are usually HR policies regarding reselling these things, which is usually "You can't". I work for a place that has entrance fees, and my employee handbook straight-up says that selling company-gift complimentary tickets is an immediate dismissal.

Answer (score 4):

Once it's yours, what you do with it is up to you, unless it came with restrictions. Management might have preferences, but if they really cared they'd tell you when they give it to you.

If you're worried about company policy, as always, ask your manager. Example script: "Hey, I appreciate the prize but I think the one I have has lots of life left in it. Would there be any objections to my finding a new home for the new one, which folks will be more interested in than if I offer the older one?

See some of the past answers about work raffles/prizes.

Comment: You suggested script sounds more like giving away then specifically selling.

Comment: Get them to approve. Then whether you sell, swap, or give away is up to you. Don't make it harder than it has to be.